# The clip path property overlaps elements and z-index doesn't work. How can I get it to stop?

Tags: css

I've tried using the z-index to move the content to the back. I've also tried to use it as a before pseudo element as my header but it still doesn't work. I've tried to use the clip path on the header but nothing seems to work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
  header {
  background-image: url('background.JPG'), 
                    url('audio.gif.JPG');
  header {
  background-image: url('background.JPG'), 
                    url('audio.gif.JPG');
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top, left ;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}

header:after{ 
  content:'';
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 1%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  z-index: -5;
}

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="HomePage.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="About.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#targetname">Show Submission</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="Sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="menu-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
<div class="hamburger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul class="aside-links">
        <li class="aside-link"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="aside-link"><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li class="aside-link"><a href="">Show Submission</a></li>
        <li class="aside-link"><a href="">Sponsors</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have selected the header tag and gave style in CSS but the header tag is missing in markup.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota Hi, I just forgot to copy it, but it's there.